# Using WakefulIntentService for long running tasks

Tags: java, android, intentservice

I have a long running background task involving network operation (e.g. tweeting a list of tweets with `Thread.sleeps` in between). This task has to last for about 20-30 mins.

What would be the recommended approach for it?

Can I use an intent service for that task?

Since an `IntentService` would stop if device falls asleep. So would a `WakefulIntentService` be a good choice?

**EDIT:**

Here is a a bit more info about the issue:

Till now I have used `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` with `AlarmManager` for periodic tasks. The `startWakeful` starts an IntentService which does the short task.

But in this current case, I would have to fire a wakeful IntentService from activity(based on users entry to fields on activity) which must do the **longer** job silently in background and exit on completion.

I just realized that WakefulIntentService is not a standard Android Class. Its an extra library available [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful).

Comment: Why don't try `Service` and combine it with `WAKE_LOCK`?

Comment: That looks a bit messy to handle. If we have already a good library in the api to do so wouldn't it be better to use it? Any cons you see in using a wakefulIntentService?